# Why media queries are not applying for max-width 425px?

Tags: css, angular, less, media-queries

I want to apply media query for `max-width 768px` and `max-width 425px`, but when I have width 425px, styles of media queries for `max-width 768px` are applying(so. with width of device 425px, width of `al-articles-tags-chip-list-container` is 600px), why?

And for `width 768px`, media queries are applying for `max-width 768px` too(as expected).

```css
.al-articles-tags-chip-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.al-text-before-search {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 22px;
}

.al-search-input-container {
  flex: 2;
}

.al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
    width: 600px;
  }

  .al-text-before-search {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 115px;
  }

  .al-text-before-search {
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .al-search-input-container {
    flex: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="al-articles-tags-chip-list-container">
  <div class="al-text-before-search">
    <span>I WOULD LIKE TO SEE</span>
  </div>
  <div class="al-search-input-container">
    <mat-form-field class="al-articles-tags-chip-list">
      ....
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, can you make it more clear what is the issue you are facing? the media query applied without issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need add meta `viewport` to head tag.

I reproduce your code it worked.

Updated: I also tried to reproduce your code in angular, it worked, you need check any conflict @media in your styles.css or not

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-check-mediaquery

[image]

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .al-articles-tags-chip-list {
  width: 100%;
}

.al-text-before-search {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 22px;
}

.al-search-input-container {
  flex: 2;
}

.al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
    width: 600px;
  }

  .al-text-before-search {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 115px;
  }

  .al-text-before-search {
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .al-search-input-container {
    flex: unset;
  }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="al-articles-tags-chip-list-container">
        <div class="al-text-before-search">
          <span>I WOULD LIKE TO SEE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="al-search-input-container">
          <mat-form-field class="al-articles-tags-chip-list">
            ....
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have in my index.html `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: can you copy my html file to test it?

Comment: I think, maybe this problem is connected with angular2. My website is on angular.

Comment: these css in component css or styles.css ?

Comment: in component css

Comment: Styles for class .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container is applied only in two places (component, that is above and another component, in which I remove styles to this class)

Comment: Hien Nguyen, I saw your stackbitz. You have the same problem as I.
Styles are applying only when width is less than 425

Comment: also I tried to comment styles.css file, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem before is that you need to create another `css` file and then put your `@media query` code there with a value of `425px` width.

e.g:

```
Style3.css    /* Your file name created */
```

and then put your following code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .al-articles-tags-chip-list-container {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 115px;
  }

  .al-text-before-search {
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .al-search-input-container {
    flex: unset;
  }
}
```

Please, let me know if this's works for you. Thanks

Comment: I use angular2+, and every component(html) has own styles file

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. 
In my display settings of laptop scale was 125% instead of 100%.
Thanks for the help!